# Map fails due to undefined property

Tags: typescript, recursion, mapreduce

Hello i am enumerating a `tree` values recursively and while some `nodes` in the tree are `undefined` i have placed guards so that it doesn't fail.Even so when `map`-ing the `children` nodes i get the error:

**Output with Error**

```
Adrian has children:Marian,Dan,
Dan is leaf
Marian has children:Liviu,Farcas,
t.ngfactory.js? 
    [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'logRecursive' of undefined
                at push../src/app/pages/tree-view/treeview.component.ts.TreeViewComponent.logRecursive (tree-view.component.ts:29)
            at Array.map (<anonymous>)
            at TreeViewComponent.push../src/app/pages/tree-view/tree-view.component.ts.TreeViewComponent.logRecursive (tree-view.component.ts:29)
            at TreeViewComponent.push../src/app/pages/tree-view/tree-view.component.ts.TreeViewComponent.ngOnInit (tree-view.component.ts:37)
            at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:18537)
            at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:19801)
            at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:19763)
            at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:20397)
            at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:20357)
            at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TreeViewComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
```

**Code**

```
 public logRecursive(model:TreeModel):number{
    if(model==null || model ==undefined){
      console.log("null");
      return 0;
    }
    if(model.children ==undefined || model.children.length==0 ){
      console.log(`${model.id} is leaf`);
      return 1;
    }

    console.log(`${model.id} has children:${model.children.reduce((x,y)=>y.id+","+x,"")}`);
    var result= model.children.map(this.logRecursive).reduce((x,y)=>x+y);
    return result;
  }
```

**Model**

```
export interface TreeModel{
    id:string;
    children:Array<TreeModel>;
}
```

**P.S** I Have tried all the possible guard combinations for `children` being `null` , `undefined` or plain `length==0` and still it doesn't fail at the first level.It fails on the second level (`children of 'Marian')`

**Input**

```
let a:TreeModel={
       id:"Adrian",
       children:[
         {id:"Dan",children:[]},
         {id:"Marian",children:[  //fails when mapping his children...
           {id:"Farcas",children:[]},
           {id:"Liviu",children:[]}
         ]}
       ]
     };
```

**Call**
`logRecursive(a);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` in the call  `this.logRecursive` is `undefined` on the recursive call. The reason for this is that in Javascript (and by extension Typescript) `this` is not decided by the function declaration but rather by the caller. So the caller can call a member function with whatever `this` it wants.

When you pass `this.logRecursive` to `map`, `map` will decide with what `this` to call `logRecursive`. `map` will just not pass any `this` to your function and thus the error.

The problem can be fixed either by calling `this.logRecursive.bind(this)` when passing the function to `map` in order to fix who `this` is. I do not recommend this in Typescript, as `bind` is very weakly typed at present (it will soon get better in 3.2 with this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028))

Another option is to use an arrow function, which will capture `this` from declaration context.

```
interface TreeModel {
    id: string;
    children: Array<TreeModel>;
}
let a: TreeModel = {
    id: "Adrian",
    children: [
        { id: "Dan", children: [] },
        {
            id: "Marian", children: [  //fails when mapping his children...
                { id: "Farcas", children: [] },
                { id: "Liviu", children: [] }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

class Comp {
    logRecursive(model: TreeModel): number {
        if (model == null || model == undefined) {
            console.log("null");
            return 0;
        }
        if (model.children == undefined || model.children.length == 0) {
            console.log(`${model.id} is leaf`);
            return 1;
        }

        console.log(`${model.id} has children:${model.children.reduce((x, y) => y.id + "," + x, "")}`);
        var result = model.children.map(m => this.logRecursive(m)).reduce((x, y) => x + y);
        return result;
    }
}
```